# Create/Edit SSIS Derived Column Task From Text/Code for Large ETL

Tags: sql-server, ssis, encoding

I have to insert a large UTF-8 encoded flat file to a 1252 encoded sql server. In order to do so, I am using SSIS to type cast each column. Is there a way, other than copy pasting through all 400 columns, to create/edit a derived column transform from text/pragmatically? I cannot use bulk insert. BCP is an option, but I had issues getting that to work.

Side note:

This is for replicating Salesforce to SQL Server. Other than pre-built solutions DBAmp, Skyia etc..., I'm open to other options. I need to make this happen quickly due to business demands.

Comment: Have you looked into python's pandas library? I'd smush it through a data frame and see what happens

Comment: @James I don't know python, but after this is all said and done that will become a priority as that seems to be the most logical solution.

Comment: I would try loading it into the sql server as it is, then converting it after its in. You'll get some more helpful error messages at the very least. Once it's in, you can use dynamic sql to recast all the columns.

Comment: @James I did think about doing a staging table with all nvarchars and then processing from there... I have noticed the error messages in SSIS aren't the most friendly. I will keep this in mind. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: You can also try BIML, it will allow you to easily generate required tasks: http://bimlscript.com/

Comment: @Piotr that looks amazing! I will give it a read. Thank you!

Comment: Flat file to SQL Server, right? In your Flat File Connection manager within SSIS, you can specify that it's UTF-8 and then the code page and dispense with the column conversions at that will happen on import. Also, Biml which I love dearly

Comment: @billinkc Indirectly flat file. Directly, SalesForce, using the kingswaysoft connector. My data is really messy or I would write it to a .csv and then pick it back up in the method you described, but that's far from a permanent solution. BIML is definitely next on my list of things to learn.